# I have a problem, someone help me, I'm on UBUNTU 20.04 and I get this error when putting apt-get update in the terminal

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates, gps

```
W: Error de GPG: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick Release: Las siguientes firmas no fueron válidas: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: El repositorio «http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick Release» no está firmado.
```

Comment: If you are on 20.04, why do you have http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick Release enabled? This would not be a good idea on 20.04, if you do not know exactly what you are doing and use the appropriate apt pins. Remove this repository from your software sources, if you have not added it on purpose.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: thx ,previously I had a problem when installing wine, this was that some lines or something like that could not be read, broken packages I think, a solution that helped me eliminate the error was does this, sudo su
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
 and put, a series of codes or lines, that would have to do with this,
old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu, the solution that I saw said that after putting this, I save it, and close it, then I put this
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade, the error is when putting apt-get update

Comment: Sorry my English is a bit bad, does this work for UBUNTU 20.04?

Comment: I have another question, is there nothing I can do to make the signature valid? , this signature: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5